Laravel's form request validation via (extending the FormRequest class) method
I've implemented the form validation in Laravel by creating my own UserStoreRequest class, which extends the FormRequest class. I'm using Ajax. BTW, whenever the validation fails, Laravel automatically creates a JSON response and sends it to the browser, including validation errors. The problem is that I need help to intercept it. I've read the documentation, and it says that whenever it encounters an error, Laravel throws this exception:

Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException.

My question is how I can intercept the JSON response that Laravel automatically generates and put things into it in my own way. Is there any way out? Can I do anything with the ValidationException class?
